# How to detect selected index in VueJS?

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this `VueJS` code:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        model: [
            { name: 'a', price: 1.00 },
            { name: 'b', price: 2.00 },
            { name: 'c', price: 3.00 },
        ],
        actived: {}
    },
    methods: {
       setActive: function(model) {
           this.actived = model;
       }
    }
});
```

And have this HTML code:

```
<select v-on:change="setActive(models[n])">
    <option v-for="n in 3">{{ n }}</option>
</select>
```

I want to update my actived data value to the selected model. For example is user change the second opcion on the select field, I want to pass the second model's datas into the actived's value.

Is there a way to detect the index of seleced option? Maybe combined with `jQuery` or other...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it with `v-model` on `select`. The selected value will pass to your `active` prop:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    model: [
        { name: 'a', price: 1.00 },
        { name: 'b', price: 2.00 },
        { name: 'c', price: 3.00 },
    ],
    active: {}
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select v-model="active"> // v-model
    <option :value="n" v-for="n in model">{{ n.name }}</option> // bind value
  </select>
  <p>{{ active }}</p>
</div>
```

Notice we loop through the `model` array itself and bind elements to `value` attribute of `option` (this value is set to selected one and passes to `active` by `v-model`).